# Q : How can we change camera settings with webrtc

Tags: camera, filtering, webrtc

we are making one to one and one to many video + audio sharing - streaming 
we manage it well without add anyhting
but we want to add filter the livestream 
like gamma , scala , consrt , white balance

ex ;  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKraR.jpg
then : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yadkb.jpg

same data diffrent settings, how can we do it ?

Comment: You should post some code and explain where you failed to proceed. SO is no code writing service.

Comment: @Markus there is a missunderstanding , i didint say write me code , i just ask how to do it . is it possible with webrtc ? or easyrtc ? or html5 canvas or any other alternative just say me that